# vba: error moving last .HPageBreaks on last row

Tags: vba, excel, row-number, page-break

I would like to fit pages so that, if the horizontal page brake is less than 8 rows from last row, the horizontal page brake should be deleted.

m is the last row on column A:

```
m = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

The macro worked well for several weeks, but in this instance (see image) it fails (run-time error '9').

[image: failing case]

```
With ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks
    If .Count > 0 Then
    'in this instance: .count = 3, m = 83
        On Error GoTo fine
        If m - .Item(.Count).Location.Row < 8 Then ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(.Count).DragOff Direction:=xlDown, RegionIndex:=1
     End If
End With
```

I don't understand: if count is 3, why doesn't row number exist?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Is that the screenshot of workbook after running the macro or before?

Comment: The screenshot is before running the macro (to be honest, the macro is quite long, so I stopped it just before the "with" sentence, and took the screenshot)